# Utilizing Google Apps script to replicate IF(SUMIF()>56,(SUMIF(),"")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, porting

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that will allow me to send emails based on if a certain cell ("A36") is equivalent to "N95" or "N64", as well as if the range (G35:G46) is equal to or greater than "56". I've achieved this in the past by utilizing an IF(SUMIF()>56,(SUMIF(),"") formula. However, my customer wishes for there to be no formulas in the document itself.

Here is what I've whittled at so far...

```
       function newFile() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var values = ss.getRange("G35:G46").getValues();
    var Ext = ss.getRange("A36").getA1Notation();
     if((values.getValue()>="56") && (Extrusion="N64")){ 
     ss.getRange=("P1:P4").setValue("2");
     }

     if ((values.getValue()>"56") && (Ext="N95")){
      ss.getRange("P1:P4").setValue("1");
      }
      }
```

As an update here is what I have come up with, I would like to however condense this into a small script. I admit I am still learning, and I would love the help.

```
    function newFile() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var Ext = ss.getRange("A36").getValue();
         if ((ss.getRange("G35").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G36").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G37").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G38").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G39").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G40").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G41").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G42").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G43").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G44").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G45").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
         if ((ss.getRange("G46").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
       ss.getRange("L35").setValue("4");}
     }

     // .setValue("4") is just my way of letting me know if the script was successful
```

Finished Update.

Looking back I realized I haven't posted a final copy of what I ended up with.

```
function checkExt() {
var ssExt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var valuesExt = ssExt.getRange("G35:G46").getValues();
var Ext = ssExt.getRange("A36").getValue();

     if ((ssExt.getRange("G35").getValue() > 55) && (Ext === "N64" || Ext === "N95")){
   sendEmails()}
```

The send Emails function ended up dividing into 3 different groups of people based on a cell's value. I'm not going to post the whole code but here is the snippet of that.

```
  var email = "";
     if (ssExt.getRange("K8").getValue() === "1Q1"){
       email = MailList1stShift}
     else if  (ssExt.getRange("K8").getValue() === "2Q1"){
       email = MailList2ndShift}
     else if  (ssExt.getRange("K8").getValue() === "3Q1"){
       email = MailList3rdShift}
```

Comment: I suggest you to start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets then perhaps you have to learn  a bit of JavaScript specially about data types, expressions, comparison operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if both these conditions are met:

- The value in `A36` is equal to `N95` or to `N64`.
- Each of the values in the range `G35:G46` is higher than 55.

If that's the case, then you can do this:

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange("G35:G46").getValues();
  var a36 = sheet.getRange("A36").getValue();
  var n95 = sheet.getRange("N95").getValue();
  var n64 = sheet.getRange("N64").getValue();
  var higher = values.every(function(value) {
    return value >= 56;
  })
  if ((a36 === n95 || a36 === n95) && higher) {
    // Send email
  }
}
```

I'm assuming you already know how to send the email via Apps Script and you just need help on checking these conditions.

#### Reference:

- [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: This does help, but I am attempting to adjust for n95 and n64 being a value I'm looking for, rather than a cell reference.

Comment: Also I don't need to look for the sum of G45:G46, but rather check each cell to see if it is 56 or greater.

Comment: @JeremyClowers I edited my question so that is checks if **all** values in `G35:G46` are equal or greater than 56. About your other comment, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Right now, it is checking whether the **value** in `N64` or the one in `N95` is equal to the **value** in `A36`. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks you lamblichusI just hopped on for the first time in months and realized I never accepted the answer. This worked well, but I figured out something myself. Looking back at my earlier response I see the poor thinking I had at the time, another example of why I should only script late when there is coffee in my hands.